# Flutter not opening on android older versions

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter app won't open in low android 11 version. Only opens in version 12. How can I fix this? Do I need to make changes in the sdk?

Comment: share android/app/build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try open android/app/build.gradle and change `minSdkVersion` `24` (for android version 7)